# Language switcher using global resources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple langauges setup under app_globalresources and would like to add a language switcher to the master template.  I have the files named Default.resx and Default.fr.resx.

Currently it is setup to auto using on the page:

```
UICulture="auto" Culture="auto"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the current thread's culture in the [InitializeCulture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) method of your page.

Assuming your language switcher is a dropdown list named `ddlLanguages` that contains specific culture codes (e.g `en-US`, `fr-FR`, `de-DE`, etc.):

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    base.InitializeCulture();

    string language = Request.Form["ddlLanguages"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(language) {
        Culture = UICulture = language;
    }
}
```